# Cannot assign to a variable used in a closure because it is borrowed

Tags: rust, closures

I'm trying to make some sections of my code easier to read by using small helper closures.

```
fn main() {
    let mut loop_index = 0;

    let get_src_index = || return loop_index % 2;
    let get_dst_index = || return (loop_index + 1) % 2;

    loop_index += 1;
}
```

There's a few more closures that make use of `get_src_index()` and `get_dst_index()`, but they are not important to the problem. The problem is that I can no longer modify `loop_index`:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `loop_index` because it is borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
4 |     let get_src_index = || return loop_index % 2;
  |                         -- borrow of `loop_index` occurs here
5 |     let get_dst_index = || return (loop_index + 1) % 2;
6 |     loop_index += 1;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `loop_index` occurs here
```

I don't quite understand why Rust doesn't allow incrementing the `loop_index` variable. Is there a more "Rusty" way of doing this?

Comment: The compiler's message does not seem to match the code above. Please make an MCVE, preferably with a link to the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/).

Comment: @E_net4 that caught me too. OP split the code into two blocks, but it was the combination of the two that had the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error message says, you can't change the value because it's borrowed. It's the same as if you had said:

```
let mut loop_index = 0;
let foo = &loop_index;
loop_index += 1;
```

You aren't allowed to [modify a value while there is an outstanding immutable borrow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html). This is a fundamental concept in Rust and underpins the safety it provides.

Why does the closure have a reference to the variable? That's the *entire point* of closures — to [capture the environment](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch13-01-closures.html#closures-can-capture-their-environment). Closures *infer* how to capture the variables based on the operations taking place inside, and in this case a reference is sufficient.

This is normally what you want because a reference is easy to pass around. In *this* case, you have numbers so there's no reason to prefer the reference. We can use the `move` keyword to move the number *into* the closure. Since numbers implement `Copy`, this will make a copy. Then the closure is completely separate from the existing value:

```
let mut loop_index = 0;

let get_src_index = move || loop_index % 2; // No need for `return`
let get_dst_index = move || (loop_index + 1) % 2;

loop_index += 1;
```

However, I don't think that these particular closures really buy you anything. Integer operations are generally cheap and conditionals are often less cheap, so doing an extra computation might be better.

---

If you needed the ability to modify the `loop_index` and have that change reflected inside the closures, you could use a `Cell`:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

fn main() {
    let mut loop_index = Cell::new(0);

    let get_src_index = || loop_index.get() % 2;
    let get_dst_index = || (loop_index.get() + 1) % 2;

    loop_index.set(loop_index.get() + 1);
}
```

---

Even *better*, in many cases you don't need to maintain your own loop index anyway. [`Iterator::enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate) takes care of it for you.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I don't think that I can use `enumerate()` here, using the `Cell` works perfectly fine though! :)